# I'd like to make a mutually exclusive tick box, so only one record in a table can have the tick at a time

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table which contains a list of cruises, and I want one to be 'Cruise of the Week'

So when the user makes a cruise 'Cruise of the Week' the previous 'Cruise of the Week' is automatically deselected.

Am I on the right lines of running a query to load the existing 'Cruise of the Week' and updating that one at the same time as the new one ? Not sure where to start....

thanks

Rich :)

Comment: Well, it's hard to tell what you are asking for, so, I edited tags back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE cruises SET active=0
UPDATE cruises SET active=1 WHERE id=123
```

You could add a unique index to active to make sure there is only one active at all time.

This might already do the trick. However, when doing it right this could create a concurrency issue. It is not likely to happen and doesn't create very big issues I think so it is doable without getting into transactions and other things to prevent the concurrency.

It could be done in one query also but don't really like that although it is doable in MySQL, pseudo code:

```
UPDATE cruises SET active = (CASE WHEN id=123 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

You gotta like it. The good thing about one query is that updates concurrency is handles by MySQL but I suspect it to be slower and it is not as clear as 2 queries.

Comment: tnx @Rich 
Which one did you use?

Answer (score 3):

Mutually exclusive checkbox is called **radiobutton**

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you're on the right track. Load the existing data and update the record when the user submits the form.

Comment: ok, so I'm actually updating two records on submit, the old cruise of the week (turning the tick off) and the new one (turning it on). Is it possible to update two records at a time?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel - let's say there's a cruise that is already cruise of the week. When the user chooses a different cruise to be cruise of the week, I want the existing one to be turned off, and the new one turned on

Comment: @Rich make it with 2 updates. Why do you want to make it in one?

Comment: well the user doesn't want to update the cruises page twice, they just want to load a cruise, and make it cruise of the week. They don't want to have to go through the cruises to turn off the other one.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE cruises 
SET active = ( CASE WHEN id = @OldCruiseId THEN 0
                    WHEN id = @NewCruiseId THEN 1
               END
             )
WHERE cruise_id IN (@OldCruiseId, @NewCruisedId)
  AND user_id = @UserId
```